# reusing std::unordered_map efficiently

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

I manage relatively small transient dictionaries in my program. My question: is it significantly more efficient to reuse them (with `mymap.clear()` after use), rather than to `delete` the old ones and create `new` ones?

Also, these dictionaries are currently implemented as `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`. This works, but if (in light of the above usage pattern) another container (**stl** or not) is preferrable, I won't hesitate to switch this implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GCC at least, `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`, at any point in time, has dynamic allocations as follows:

- 1 allocation for an array of buckets, which each hold iterators (likely implemented as pointers) into a singly linked list of nodes (generally between 1x and 2x your peak element count), or a sentinel iterator state when no elements hashed to that bucket
- #elements allocations: there's a node with a next pointer, a hash value (yes, it saves it!), and the `std::string` and `int` data
- #keys longer than 15: any `std::string` too long for the Short String Optimisation (where text content is stored directly in the `std::string` object), will have a pointer to a dynamically allocated text buffer

When you do a `.clear()` the latter two categories of allocations are deallocated.  When the container itself is destructed, only one extra deallocation is done.

So, I wouldn't expect much performance improvement from keeping the `unordered_map`s around.

If you care about performance, look more carefully at your data.  Is there an upper bound to string length?  If there is and it's not large (e.g. 8 or 16 bytes), you could grab a hash table using open-addressing a.k.a. closed-hashing where the keys and values are stored directly in the buckets, so there's just one dynamic allocation going on.  That could be expected to give you a large performance improvement (but always measure).

Answer (score 3):

Did you profile it? Because right now it's just a lot of guesswork.

Consider that `new` and `delete` on the `std::unordered_map` just add the overhead of instanciating / tearing down of the container itself. `std::unordered_map::clear` internally will still call `delete` on every object it holds, so that it's destructor is invoked. There might be a fancy allocator involved, that implements a pool of identically sized slots for the container elements to save on the memory management overhead.

Depending on the complexity of the contained objects it may, or may not be more sensible, to use a plain `std::vector`

You'll have to profile where your overhead is. *But more importantly, only go through the work, if this is a part of your program that causes statistically significant slowdown. You should choose ease of readability and implementation clarity above micro optimizations.*

Comment: Thanks, your point is clearly taken. My trouble is that this library will be a small part of a big application, and I need to keep the footprint as small as possible. Using a vector as a container is not a good choice because populating the dictionary (inserting new entries or adding to existing ones) will happen on the UI thread and must be super-fast.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Then on a *real* computer (not a theoretical compsci lecture machine) a vector might actually be the *best* choice, because below a certain size threshold it's much nicer to the cache hierarchy. For a vector you're doing a single, large allocation once (with `std::vector::reserve`) and then have elements contiguous in memory, wheras with a map, it's a lot of disjointed, small allocations, that are all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't any performance-advantage to `.clear()` and reuse over just getting a new node-based container, it's nearly the same amount of work.

If you know the maximum size of your dictionary, and it is reasonably small, consider using a custom allocator for the nodes.

That way, you might get things more compact and save on allocation overhead.

Aside from that, other containers which avoid allocating thousands of individual nodes outside the standard library are a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

> This works, but if (in light of the above usage pattern) another container (stl or not) is preferrable, I won't hesitate to switch this implementation.

Ok choice for the start. If you wanna try something else:

- Consider [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)
- Consider other hash maps from other libraries, like [abseil](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/container) library

Measure performance on real scenario with real data to see if alternatives are worth using.

Comment: abseil is also recommended in https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/rdxOHKzQmRY, in a context that does resemble my use case!